# How can I convert list of Dictionary in Python to list of Tuples?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a big list of dictionaries like this one:

```
[{'emailAddress': 'abc@gmail.com', 'firstName': 'JOSHI', 'lastName': 'Messi', 'dropdownMenu2': 'California', 'dropdownMenu': 'Geotech', 'singleLineText': 'Temp LLC', 'mobilePhone': '+9XXXXXXX', 'id': '4514', 'submittedAt': '1641392678'}, {'emailAddress': 'tets@qqq.com', 'firstName': 'Ronaldo', 'lastName': 'Crist7', 'dropdownMenu2': 'Dubai', 'dropdownMenu': 'Investigation', 'singleLineText': 'Company LTD', 'mobilePhone': '+YYYYYYYYY', 'id': '4512', 'submittedAt': '1641389624'}]
```

It's basically data inserted in this list of dict:

```
[{'emailAddress': 'X', 'firstName': 'X', 'lastName': 'X', 'dropdownMenu2': 'X', 'dropdownMenu': 'X', 'singleLineText': 'X', 'mobilePhone': 'X', 'id': 'X', 'submittedAt': 'X'}]
```

where `X` is the value.

I'm trying to get it in this format:

```
[ ('abc@gmail.com' , 'JOSHI' , 'Messi' ,'California', 'Geotech' , 'Temp LLC','+9XXXXXXX' , '4514' ,'1641392678') , ('tets@qqq.com' , 'Ronaldo' , 'Crist7' , 'Dubai' , 'Investigation' , 'Company LTD' , '+YYYYYYYYY' , '4512' , '1641389624')]
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is:

1. convert the big data list from dictionary list to tuple list
2. extract the values from the list so later on I can push it to a MySQL DB

Can someone please help?

I have tried converting the dict to JSON and then convert again to tuple but it didn't work.

Comment: `[tuple(x.values()) for x in d]`!?

Comment: Note that, although dictionaries now retain insertion order, they aren't semantically ordered collections - depending on how your first list is created it's entirely possible that you'll end up with tuples where the values are in different orders. Being explicit about the key order you intend would probably be wise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to first create your list
You can create your tuple and take only the values by using:

`yournewtuple = tuple(yourdict.values())`

With this you will get only the values of your dictionnary and you have just to do:

`finalList.append(yournewtuple)` and so on...

My solution can be more optimized than this but I can't give you the whole solution to your question because I don't know what do you want exactly to do but here is your list of tuples from your dict